# Is there any way to create call recording app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, phone-call, recording, call-recording

So, I have tried to develop an application for call recording :

- By using [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) to record a call and I am detecting call state using [phone_state_i](https://pub.dev/packages/phone_state_i) but succeeded to record the call with the voice of MICROPHONE only cannot record the voice of other people (INCOMING voice).
- Then I tried to record calls using android through [flutter native integration](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) but unable to achieve. So even here I got succeeded to record only the voice of a microphone.

I guess I am unable to get the concept of VOICE_DOWNLINK and VOICE_UPLINK. And got to know that VOICE_CALL is deprecated. So, I am badly stuck and need some expert advice.

Comment: So, I got to know after lot of research that we cannot achieve call recording directly i.e through flutter or android, we need to use native libraries of call recording or sound recording to do so. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231232/android-call-recording-incoming-voice-not-getting-recorded) for more information of call recording using ndk.

Answer (score 0):

Recording phone calls is challenging due to privacy laws and technical limitations. VOICE_CALL audio source is deprecated on Android 10. VOICE_DOWNLINK and VOICE_UPLINK are no longer working on newer Android versions. Official API for recording both sides of the conversation is not available. Some apps use MIC audio source but has limitations. OEM-specific APIs or workarounds may work for specific devices, but not all.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that until now, there is still [no package available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63463204/8342742) for this functionality.

> That kind of functionality would have to be provided by a flutter
> plugin that integrates with native call recording APIs. That kind of a
> bridge is possible on older versions of Android but it became much
> harder after Marshmallow - Google removed the official call recording
> API.
>
> The only 100% working/future proof implementations of call recording
> on Android and iOS would require the devices to be rooted/jailbroken.

Check also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027480/flutter-based-call-recording-app-with-native-ui-integration).

> In short, mentioned via comments, you’ll have to refer to
> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels
> to do it yourself by implementing platform-specific code such as
> CallKit/ConnectionService.
>
> First, because there’s currently likely no Flutter library that has
> already conveniently packaged this up for you, at least not at
> https://pub.dev/flutter, so this is why you need to do it yourself.
>
> Now, assuming all the restrictions, permissions, rooting,
> jailbreaking, etc. poses no issue to you, then you would need to
> implement these APIs natively in iOS/Android first